# AWS opswork docker: Missing Cookbooks:No such cookbook: docker

Tags: docker, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I am trying to deploy dockers with opswork but the setup fails. Logs are copied below.

```
+================================================================================+
+Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:+
+================================================================================+

+Missing Cookbooks:+
+------------------+
+No such cookbook: docker+

+Expanded Run List:+
+------------------+
+* cookbook_sr::install+
+* cookbook_sr::docker-deploy+

+Platform:+
+---------+
```

**My recipes are,**

1) install.rb

```
case node[:platform]
when "ubuntu","debian"
  package "docker.io" do
    action :install
  end
when 'centos','redhat','fedora','amazon'
  package "docker" do
    action :install
  end
end

service "docker" do
  action :start
end
```

2) docker-deploy.rb

```
include_recipe 'deploy'

node[:deploy].each do |application, deploy|

  if node[:opsworks][:instance][:layers].first != deploy[:environment_variables][:layer]
    Chef::Log.debug("Skipping deploy::docker application #{application} as it is not deployed to this layer")
    next
  end

  opsworks_deploy_dir do
    user deploy[:user]
    group deploy[:group]
    path deploy[:deploy_to]
  end

  opsworks_deploy do
    deploy_data deploy
    app application
  end

  bash "docker-cleanup" do
    user "root"
    code <<-EOH
      if docker ps | grep #{deploy[:application]}; 
      then
        docker stop #{deploy[:application]}
        sleep 3
        docker rm #{deploy[:application]}
        sleep 3
      fi
      if docker images | grep #{deploy[:application]}; 
      then
        docker rmi #{deploy[:application]}
      fi
    EOH
  end

  bash "docker-build" do
    user "root"
    cwd "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current"
    code <<-EOH
     docker build -t=#{deploy[:application]} . > #{deploy[:application]}-docker.out
    EOH
  end

  dockerenvs = " "
  deploy[:environment_variables].each do |key, value|
    dockerenvs=dockerenvs+" -e "+key+"="+value
  end

  bash "docker-run" do
    user "root"
    cwd "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current"
    code <<-EOH
      docker run #{dockerenvs} -p #{node[:opsworks][:instance][:private_ip]}:#{deploy[:environment_variables][:service_port]}:#{deploy[:environment_variables][:container_port]} --name #{deploy[:application]} -d #{deploy[:application]}
    EOH
  end

end
```

3) metadata.rb

```
name              "creditcard_docker"
maintainer        "xxxx"
maintainer_email  "contact@xxxx.com"
license           "Apache 2.0"
description       "AWS opsworks docker"
version           "1.0"

depends 'docker', '~> 2.0'
```

**My docker layer is configured as**

```
setup:   cookbook_sr::install
deploy:  cookbook_sr::docker-deploy
```

Any idea how to set it up (chef 12), or is there any tutorial to follow?

Answer (score 1):

It should be rather a comment to your question than an answer (but I've too few points).

Have you tried ty create Berksfile with docker cookbook?

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

metadata
```

or

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

cookbook "docker"
```